# Writing a MAPLE procedure for adding the legends inside in plots

Tags: plot, legend, maple

How to write a procedure to add the legends of any given two functions to the suitable location in the graphs? Or we can select the location at the beginning of the procedure (like left-top, right-bottom etc.)?

**For example;** Let's consider the sin(x) and cos(x), and try to write a Maple code as follows:

```
restart: 
with(plottools):  with(plots):
f:=x->sin(x):
g:=x->cos(x):
A:=plot(f(x), x=0..2*3.14, style=pointline, symbol= diamond, color=red, symbolsize=11, numpoints=40, adaptive=false):
B:=plot(g(x), x=0..2*3.14, style=pointline, symbol= solidcircle, color=blue, symbolsize=11, numpoints=40, adaptive=false):

location:=0.8:
L1, L2:=line([2.75,location],[3.2,location],color=red), line([3.65,location],[4.1,location],color=blue):

P1:=plot([seq([2.75+i*(3.2-2.75)/3,location], i=1..2)],style=point,symbol= diamond, color=red, symbolsize=11):
P2:=plot([seq([3.65+i*(3.2-2.75)/3,location], i=1..2)],style=point,symbol= solidcircle, color=blue, symbolsize=11):

T:=textplot([[3.4,location,sin(x)],[4.3,location,cos(x)]]):

P:=polygon([[2.7,0.7],[2.7,0.9],[4.5,0.9],[4.5,0.7]], style=line, thickness=0):
plots:-display(A, B, P, L1, L2, T, P1, P2, scaling=constrained, size=[800,300],axes=boxed);
```

[The image of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVdND.png)

Comment: So your procedure must find empty space within the plot that can accomodate the constructed (faked) legend? That could involve serious programming effort. What if none such space exists: should it overlap the curves or reduce the font, or throw an error, or...? And how robust is this idea, given that the user may not wish the legend to zoom in along with the curves, or be subject to a transformation done to the whole, etc. I think it would be better if the `legendstyle` option allowed for placement within the plot proper, as new substructure. The GUI plot renderer would handle this better.

Comment: Thanks for your interest dear @acer. You're right. If none space exists, in my opinion, firstly the user select the location of legends, the procedure should add a (non-transparent) white rectangular on the location and then should add the legends on the rectangular. There may be an option to remove the rectangular like "rectangular=off" , also an option change the size etc.